# Web Scrapping via python show AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'full_text'

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, woocommerce

Scrap the data from the website by using python.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import http.client
http.client._MAXHEADERS = 1000
url='https://agedcarestore.com.au/product-category/physio-products/arthritis/'

s=HTMLSession()
r=s.get(url)
print(r.html.find('#header'))

items=r.html.find('div.product-small.box')
print(items)

def get_links(url):
    r=s.get(url)
    items=r.html.find('div.product-small.box')
    links=[]
    for item in items:
        links.append(item.find('a',first=True).attrs['href'])
        
    return links
print(get_links(url))
def get_product(link):
    r=s.get(link)
    
    title=r.html.find('h1',first=True).full_text
    price=r.html.find('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount bdi')[1].full_text
    sku=r.html.find('nav.ruk_rating_snippet data-sku',first=True).full_text
    tag = r.html.find('a[rel=tag]', first=True).full_text
    sku = r.html.find('span.sku', first=True).full_text

    product = {
        'title': title.strip(),
        'price': price.strip(),
        'tag': tag.strip(),
        'sku': sku.strip()
    }
    print(product)
    return product 

results = []
links = get_links(url)

for link in links:
    results.append(get_product(link))
    time.sleep(1)

with open('version1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    fc = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=results[0].keys(),)
    fc.writeheader()
```

I want extract the data from the website which built on woocommerce, but my python code showed the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'full_text'

how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the full traceback message so we can see the exact error. But generally, what if one of these things you are searching for, doesn't exist? This is the error that you'd expect. So, what do you want to do in that case? It may be reasonable to catch that error, post a message and exit.

Comment: `.find()` did not find the target text, so it returned None, so you ended up trying to access the `.full_text` attribute of a None object.

Comment: Can you  confirm the real url of the page?

Comment: Please edit your question write a clear title

Comment: I have updated the question with the clear title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to get `.full_text` without checking if `find` returned something. You should **remove the `.full_text` part** from the lines and just build `product` with the checks, like

```py
    product = {
        'title': title.full_text.strip() if title else 'DEFAULT_TITLE',
        'price': price[0].full_text.strip() if price else 'DEFAULT_PRICE', # remove [0] from find as well
        'tag': tag.full_text.strip() if tag else 'DEFAULT_TAG',
        'sku': sku.full_text.strip() if sku else 'DEFAULT_SKU',
    }
```

[Btw, why are there 2 `sku` lines? The first line gets over-written by the second, so it's not really doing anything...]

[Also, in `get_links`, you should maybe change the selector to `'div.product-small.box:has(a[href])'` and `item.find('a[href]',first=True)` to be safer and avoid None-type errors there as well.]